# maximum index in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, max

I have this array:

```
$number= array(

                array([0]=>2,[1]=>2)
                array([0]=>2,[1]=>2,[2]=>2,[3]=>2)
                array([0]=>2,[1]=>2,[2]=>2)
                array([0]=>2,[1]=>2)
)
```

I want maximum index in this array. for this array is 4.

Comment: Maximum number of elements in one of the inner arrays is 4, maximum index is 3. What did you try ?

Comment: yes, i want maximum element

Comment: Maximum **number** of elements or maximum element ?

Comment: Maximum number of elements

Comment: It can be achieved with a simple for-loop, what have you tried ?

Comment: yea but i can't. i featch my array from mysql with mysql_fetch_array and store it by array()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This code tested and works for your array**. Of course array_map with count func is best solution for dimention 1 max count

```
<?php
    $number= array(

                    array(0=>2,1=>2),
                    array(0=>2,1=>2,2=>2,3=>2),
                    array(0=>2,1=>2,2=>2),
                    array(0=>2,1=>2),
    );

    $ak = array_values($number);
    for($i;$i<count($number);$i++){
    $c[] = count($ak[$i]);
    }
    echo max($c);
    ?>
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1353507690, 1353595005,1353507690, [datestring] => 1353507690, 1353595005,1353507690, [1] => 2012-11-21 [rpt_date] => 2012-11-21 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1353595005, 1353595005 [datestring] => 1353595005, 1353595005 [1] => 2012-11-22 [rpt_date] => 2012-11-22 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1353854205, 1353853290,1353854205, ,1353854205, 1353854205 [datestring] => 1353854205, 1353853290,1353854205, ,1353854205, 1353854205 [1] => 2012-11-25 [rpt_date] => 2012-11-25 ))

Comment: How does your method differ from what @xdazz suggested?

Comment: array_map only calculates level 1 of array with this block you can edit for other levels also.For example you want to calculate $array[a][b][c][d], think if you need to calculate max count of "d" that is located at level 4 or dimention 4 array_pop doesnt work at this.

Answer (score 8):

You may mean this:

```
echo max(array_map('count', $number));
```

Comment: This how I'd do it, but ...code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.  Even the simplest solutions should be accompanied by a plan English explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Write a loop that iterates over the array.  For each array in the array, get the number of elements in that array, and if it's greater than the greatest so far (say, `$max`), set `$max` to the number of elements.  Then, when you're done with the loop over the array, `$max` has your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use count() function:

```
$max = count($number); // returns 4
```

**Update**

Your question is not clear enough. Provided comments and answers indicate that you want to get number of elements that exists in the array that have elements more than the other arrays within the `$number` array. And in this case [`@xdazz`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz) answer is the best one for you. And it's better and more correct to write your `$number` array like this:

```
$number = array(
    array(1, 2),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(1, 2)
);
```

Comment: it's not work and it's not in my mind. :(

Comment: @BOGUSBOGUS: It is not clear from your question that you did not ask for that. Improve your question! Also it's trivial what you ask for.

Comment: @BOGUSBOGUS take a look at the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$data = array(
    "apples" =>
        array("red", "yellow", "pineapples","enam"),
    "bananas" =>
        array("small", "medium", "big","enam","enam"),
    "vegs" =>
        array("potatoes", "carrots", "onions")
);

foreach($data as $in_arr){
    $count = count($in_arr);
    if($count>$max)$max = $count;
}
echo "The max:".$max;
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.